# Blackberry Cod Signing without BlackBerry JDE

Tags: blackberry, code-signing, blackberry-jde

I want to Sign a application that my friend sent me for signing. The reason have no access to my primary pc currently. So can i just sign the application? I have new keys with me.

```
java -jar SignatureTool.jar [-p <password>][-a][-c][-C][-f [-d] inputFile][-r directory ][-help] ( codFile (codFile) ... | csiFile )
```

Please provide me link to this file

```
SignatureTool.jar
```

From my exp. i assume that that signing is only dependent on this file. Can any one please upload and provide me link to this file. There is no such file when i goggled about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the link to SingatureTool.jar](http://www.mediafire.com/?3wydydri4ddmdng)

I think you know that you also need key files from RIM to sign an application.

Comment: Thanks Rafael , appreciate your help

Comment: Sorry. but i think i can't install keys without Blackberry JDE.

Comment: You need either BlackBerry JDE or BlackBerry Eclipse Plugin installed to import keys and work with them. You can download it here: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse